# How to access Hilt module in Application class

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have an application class `MainApplication`

[image]

I need to access to a Hilt module in this class:

[image]

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Do you want to inject the HceRepository in  MApplication class?

Comment: @gowtham6672 Exactly

Comment: I think you should be abel to do it after oncreate call. what's the issue?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApplication : MultiDexApplication() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var hceRepository: HceRepository //new

    override fun onCreate() {
        // Try to call anything of hceRepository in here.
    }
}
```

Do the field injection in the Application class. This should be enough